# android studio , Connot resolve any new library as dependency

Tags: android

I'm using android studio for my project , now , everytime I find a library in google and want to add that library and use it , I get this error :

[image]

I've tested , and seen that , **any** library that I want to add , I get that error .

here is my gradle.build

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.agahi.www.adevertisement"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.3'
**compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:1.8.3'** ------> I added this line , and got the error again
}
```

And here is my another gradle file :

```
 buildscript {
     repositories {
         jcenter()
         mavenCentral()
     }
     dependencies {
         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
     }
 }

 allprojects {
     repositories {
         jcenter()
     }
 }
```

what should I do ?

This is a shame that most of my time , gets to fix android studio bugs and errors , instead of actual coding and thinking :(

EDIT : 
I want to use this library , : https://github.com/rengwuxian/MaterialEditText

EDIT :

Even if I try to make a completely new project and add libraries , I face same error .

Comment: What does your `repositories` closure contain? I have no problem adding `compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:1.8.3'` to a brand-new project created via the Android Studio new-project wizard.

Comment: sorry :( , But I don't know what is my repositories closure, ? can you help ?

Comment: Assuming that you have a fairly normal Android Studio project, you should have two `build.gradle` files. One will be in the `app/` module, which would appear to be what you posted here. The other will be in the project root. Please edit your question and post that `build.gradle` file here as well.

Comment: @CommonsWare , I added the file you said ,

Comment: Can you successfully visit http://jcenter.bintray.com/ in a Web browser on your development machine? It feels like you cannot reach the Maven repository represented by `jcenter()`.

Comment: Yes , I see a long list in my browser ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally made it work , 
I went to the default setting of android studio
The in the gradle section
there was a checkbox that was : gradle work offline 
I remove the tik .

By the way , this was default android sturio configuration , that is embarrassing.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to gradle  file.

> > ```
> > repositories {
> >   jcenter()
> >   mavenCentral()  }
> > ```

Comment: @xe4me: Based on what you put in the question, you added `mavenCentral()` to the `repositories` closure inside the `buildscript` closure. You will see a second `repositories` closure later in that `build.gradle` file, this one inside `allprojects`. Add `mavenCentral()` to that `repositories` closure.

Comment: still same error :( 
I want to kill myself  , I've missed PHP :( , everything was great there

Comment: go to Project Structure in File. select App. in the Library Repository is there "jcenter, mavenCentral" without the " ? an add the the code i posted in the build.gradle file (App)

Comment: No , these 2 are not there , should I write them there ? @Ruben Luz

Answer (score 0):

Ensure these lines in the build.gradle file of the project and sync.
It will work for sure.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```